# How to select div which is not parent nor sibling of a div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have many divs like this

```
        <div class="body-row row m-0">
            <div class="px-2 col-3">
                <select name="item_type[]" class="form-control invoiceType" required>
                    <option value="newitem">New Item</option>
                    <option value="presetitem">Present Item</option>
                    <option value="discount">Discount</option>
                    <option value="subsidy">Subsidy</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="px-2 col-6 item-description" style="display: flex;">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]" placeholder="Add Invoice Description" required style="flex: 1">
            </div>
            <div class="px-2 col-2">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount[]" placeholder="0" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 del-icon-container"><i class="fas fa-trash del-invoice-item"></i></div>
        </div>
```

I want to select only `item-description`, and remove the content in it

```
$(document).on('change', '.invoiceType',function() {
        var invoiceType = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        if(invoiceType == 'newitem') {
            $('.item-description').empty();
            $('.item-description').append(`
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]" placeholder="Add Invoice Description" required style="flex: 1">
            `);
        } 
    });
```

Currently it make changes to all divs because they have all same name of classes

Comment: You can change this `$('.item-description')` to `$(this).closest("div").next(".item-description").empty()`

Comment: If you can modify the html you could also add a data attribute in your select that would reference "its" itemDescription via a unique id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's DOM traversal methods to relate elements to each other based on a reference to an element in an event handler. In this case you can use `closest()` to find a common parent container, then `find()` to get the element you require.

Note in the example below that the `:selected` selector is not necessary - you can get the `val()` from the `select` directly. In addition you can combine `empty()` and `append()` by setting the `html()` of the element.

```js
$(document).on('change', '.invoiceType', function() {
  console.log('change');
  let $field = $(this);
  let invoiceType = $field.val(); // :selected not needed
  
  if (invoiceType === 'newitem') {
    $field.closest('.body-row').find('.item-description').html(`<input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]" placeholder="Add Invoice Description" required style="flex: 1">`);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="body-row row m-0">
  <div class="px-2 col-3">
    <select name="item_type[]" class="form-control invoiceType" required>
      <option value="newitem">New Item</option>
      <option value="presetitem">Present Item</option>
      <option value="discount">Discount</option>
      <option value="subsidy">Subsidy</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="px-2 col-6 item-description" style="display: flex;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]" placeholder="Add Invoice Description" required style="flex: 1">
  </div>
  <div class="px-2 col-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount[]" placeholder="0" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1 del-icon-container"><i class="fas fa-trash del-invoice-item"></i></div>
</div>

<div class="body-row row m-0">
  <div class="px-2 col-3">
    <select name="item_type[]" class="form-control invoiceType" required>
      <option value="newitem">New Item</option>
      <option value="presetitem">Present Item</option>
      <option value="discount">Discount</option>
      <option value="subsidy">Subsidy</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="px-2 col-6 item-description" style="display: flex;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]" placeholder="Add Invoice Description" required style="flex: 1">
  </div>
  <div class="px-2 col-2">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="amount[]" placeholder="0" required>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1 del-icon-container"><i class="fas fa-trash del-invoice-item"></i></div>
</div>
```

Finally, as an aside, note that creating an entirely new `input` and overwriting the content of the div that contains it is a little redundant. Simply calling `val('')` on the input will suffice is all you need to do is clear its value:

```
$field.closest('.body-row').find('.item-description input').val('');
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't have to use the last one because I am adding different html when itemInvoice value is change

Comment: That makes sense then :) Glad to help